# IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered on a sub classed Receiver within a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, receiver

I have a Receiver sub classed within a Fragment and a accompanying Service that sends a message to the Broadcast Receiver to show a toast indeterminately pending certain conditions. I also have a boolean value to tell me if the Receiver is running or not. The receiver is registered on click of a list Item as shown.

```
if(!ReceiverON){
                              getActivity().registerReceiver(new Receiver(), filter);
                              ReceiverON=true;
                            }
```

I want to Unregister it once the Fragment is Destroyed. I know The docs say it should  be Unregistered in OnPause but during onPause I use the Receiver in conjuction with a service to persist a toast. In my On Destroy I Unregister is as below

```
if( ReceiverON){
             ReceiverON=false;
            Log.i("Log on Destroy", "Receiver ON...Destroying");
            getActivity().unregisterReceiver(new Receiver());
            if(getActivity().startService(ServiceIntent) != null) { 
                getActivity().stopService(ServiceIntent);
             }

        }
```

If I do as above the app crashes with IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered  on the Unregister line. If I comment out that line I get a error log about not unregistering  my Receiver. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered

Because you are passing different object of `Receiver` class in `unregisterReceiver` method. use same object which you have passed in `registerReceiver` for unregister broadcast receiver:

**->** Create an object of `Receiver` class at class level:

```
private Receiver objReceiver;
```

**->** Initialize `objReceiver` object before calling `registerReceiver` method:

```
objReceiver=new Receiver();
getActivity().registerReceiver(objReceiver, filter);
```

**->** Pass `objReceiver` object to `unregisterReceiver` :

```
  if(objReceiver !=null)
    getActivity().unregisterReceiver(objReceiver);
```

Comment: You my friend deserve an Upvote and a cold beer to go with it